# Bridge rectifier overheating

Tags: power-supply, bridge-rectifier

I bought a cheap [LED strip](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/552852/13364) with a power supply unit from Aliexpress. After using it for some time I noticed that PSU is overheating in one spot to the point where the label looks [burned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScTIl.jpg).

I opened it and it looks like the bridge rectifier TD1KN is [overheating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2o7w.jpg). The PSU is rated @ 12V/5A, the LED strip draws 1.1A. <s>The datasheet of the rectifier [specifies](https://download.datasheets.com/pdfs/2012/10/11/2/48/27/827/lon_/manual/download.phphsfiletd10jn10kn-4.pdfhdfiletecfile01349417445.pdf) the max current is 1A (if I'm reading it correctly). If so, does it mean 5A on the label is a lie?</s> (see comments)

Should I be worried? Can I fix it? Should I buy a new PSU?

Edit: looks like the cap is [busted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXXI8.jpg). Could it be the culprit or maybe it got damaged because of the temperature? (it's right on the other side of the board)

Comment: The rectifier is on the 120V mains side. Even if you pulled 5A out on the 12V side that rectifier would only see a little more than 0.5A.

Comment: Is it? I thought it would be after the transformer?..

Comment: That's a [switch-mode power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply#Theory_of_operation).

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: I stopped reading after you said this: *I bought a cheap LED strip with a power supply unit from Aliexpress*